# Javascript audio does not stop and play multiple tracks simultaniously

Tags: javascript, html, function, audio, mp3

Javascript audio does not stop and play multiple tracks simultaniously.

I'm trying to shuffle randomly number of MP3/WAV tracks and it working nicely up until the point it suppose to stop the last track so there is a live merge between the previous tracks and it obviously sounds like a mess.

I bet it's a tiny tweak to solve that issue but... :)

anyways Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>&nbsp;</title>
</head>
<body>
```

Thanks in advance for your kind help :D

```
var t=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},3000);

var files=
[
    'Hezi-Gangina#1.mp3',
    'Hezi-Gangina#2.mp3',
    'Hezi-Gangina#3.mp3',
    'Hezi-Gangina#4.mp3'
];

function myTimer()
{

    if(audio)
    {
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime=0;
        delete audio;
    }

    var i=Math.floor(Math.random()*files.length);
    var url=files[i];

    var audio=new Audio(url);

    audio.play();

    document.title=url.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/,'');

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the interval's callback function `myTimer()`.

Let's have a look:

```
if(audio)
{
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime=0;
    delete audio;
}
```

Above, you're checking for the existence of the variable `audio` but this condition won't ever be true. Why? It's defined **after** this check **and** it's defined in the local scope of the callback function:

```
var audio=new Audio(url);
audio.play();
```

So the local variable will be re-defined on each call to myTimer and just 'lives' inside this function.

To fix this, you need to make audio a **global variable** and modify the if check to like this:

```
if(audio != null)
```

this will make sure it won't try to stop the audio the first time.

Here's your modified code:

```
var audio=null;
var t=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},3000);
var files=
[
    'Hezi-Gangina#1.mp3',
    'Hezi-Gangina#2.mp3',
    'Hezi-Gangina#3.mp3',
    'Hezi-Gangina#4.mp3'
];

function myTimer()
{
    if(audio != null)
    {
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime=0;
        delete audio;
    }

    var i=Math.floor(Math.random()*files.length);
    var url=files[i];

    audio=new Audio(url);
    audio.play();
}
```